# jquery rotate rectangle around x y axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, rotation, transform

I have a rectangle div placed left top 200px wide and 100% high. I want to put an image inside this div, however the image is in landscape (w:1024 h: 200) I thought no prob just rotate it, which I can do but I cant position it. So need some help here positioning top left!

```
$('.header_rotate').css({                              
transform: 'rotate('+ -90 +'deg)',                                                                                    
backgroundColor: 'green',
height: '100%',
width: '200'                      
})

<div class="header">
  <div class="header_rotate">
      <img id="logo" src="img/Logo_Design_2048x410.png" />
  </div>
 </div>
```

[JsFiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/dRvy8/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the transform:rotate(90deg) you can add translateX and translateY to position it just right.

```
$('.header_rotate').css({

  transform: 'translateX(-130px) translateY(200px) rotate(90deg)',
  backgroundColor: 'green',
  height: '200',
  width: '600',
});
```

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/dRvy8/2/